# Add blog_details to wp_get_sites list

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am looking to add blog details to the following dropdown list to replace $site['domain'] in the option value with the detail 'blogname'. I also want to keep  $site['domain'] in the option content.

```
function blavou_existing_sites() {
echo '<div id="blav-wrapper">';
echo '<div class="blav-nav-wrapper">';
echo '<ul class="blav-drop">';
echo '<form action="../">';
echo '<select name="mySelectbox" id="mySelectbox">';
echo '<option value="">Choose Existing</option>';
$sites = wp_get_sites();
foreach ($sites as $site) {
    printf( '<option value="http://'.$site['domain'].'/wp-admin/">'.$site['domain'].'</option>');
}  
echo '</select>';
echo '<input type="button" onclick="window.open(this.form.mySelectbox.options[this.form.mySelectbox.selectedIndex].value,\'_top\')" value="Confirm">';
echo '</form>';
echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

}

Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the get blog details() function:

```
 foreach ($sites as $site) {
    $details = get blog details($site['blog_id']);
    printf( '<option value="%s">%s (%s)</option>', 'http://'.$site['domain'].'/wp-admin/', $details->blogname, $site['domain'] );
 }
```

This should give you options like "blogname (url)".